# How to schedule an adonisjs command with plesk scheduler?

Tags: node.js, plesk, adonisjs-ace

I have this created command called 'newsletter'. When I call 'adonis newsletter' on local, it works just fine. But when I try to run with scheduler on plesk with 'cd httpdocs; node ace newsletter', it was completed with this error:

```
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/node_modules/@adonisjs/ignitor/src/Ignitor/index.js:286
async _bootProviders () {
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:44...
```

anyone know what is wrong? when i tried 'cd httpdocs; adonis newsletter' it gaves error too, it said that command not found.. my node version is 14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when I use this command :

```
cd httpdocs; /opt/plesk/node/v16.13.1/bin/node ace newsletter;
```